# Rails how to attach object creation to a user session for user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to rails. I'm working on a simple app for creating and sharing collection with friends. i have Users, who have items. These items belong to categories, which it turn have subcategories. Users can place comments on items

User has_many items, Item belongs_to user

Category has_many items, Items belong to category

Category has_many subcategories, Subcategories belong_to category

item has_many comments, comments belong to item.

I've managed to create a separate from for creating comments, with options to select categories and subcategories. This automatically updates the category_id and subcategory_id in the items table:

views/item/new.html.erb

```
div class="field">
  <%= f.label :item_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :category_type, prompt: true %>
 </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subcategory %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :subcategory_id, @subcategories, :id, :sub_type, prompt: true %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 7%>
 </div>

 <div class="actions"> 
    <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

controllers/items_contoller.rb

class ItemsController < ApplicationController

```
   def index
    @items = Item.all

  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
    @categories = Category.all
    @subcategories = Subcategory.all 

  end

  def edit
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.find.all
    @subcategories = Subcategory.all 

  end

  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])

     render 'show'
    end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])

    if @item.save
      flash[:success] = "Added new item #{@item}"
      redirect_to @item
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])

    if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
     flash[:success] = "Successfully updated item!"
    redirect_to @item 
    else
     render 'edit'
    end  
  end

  def destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Successfully deleted category!"
    redirect_to categories_url, notice: "deleted"
  end

end
```

But I have a problem with associating the particular item to a user when creationg or editing. I already have a working session management for users. Users can login and logout. i would like to be able to also update the user_id column in the items table with the corresponding user_id of the user in the current session but I have no idea how to go about it. If it helps, below is how I have handle session management

sessions_controller.rb

class SessionsController < ApplicationController

```
 def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
     render 'new', notice:"Invalid email/password combination" 
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end 

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

many thanks in advance for your anticipated respinse

Comment: are you creating foreign_keys in the associating tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])
    @item.user_id = current_user.id

    # ...
  end
end
```

Not sure if it is what you're looking for.

Comment: Don't forget to accept it. It will help you to get more responses in the future.